# "xampp" server is not open in windows 10 after installing it

Tags: apache, xampp, windows-10

I have installed xampp and it's not open. In C drive xampp folders are there but when I search at start menu it is not shown

Comment: I'm not sure that Stack Overflow is the right place to ask these kind of questions. That being said, maybe you skipped an option to add a start menu shortcut while installing it? Can you run it from the xampp folder by double clicking on xampp.exe directly?

Comment: yes @nevda_scout

Comment: If it runs from the exe, then you could manually add a start menu shortcut. Try to search for this on Google

Comment: @nevada_scout it works. thanks